# Coloured charts - VBA Excel 2007 - data source colours to be reflected within the stack charts

Tags: vba, colors, charts, excel-2010

I have worksheet which contains several bar charts, and the source data for those charts is colour coded and on the same worksheet. I have the code below which I was hoping would turn the colours of the bars in the charts the same colours as the source data, but its not working, it just turns all the bars white. Does anyone have any idea why this code isnt working and matching the colours? very grateful for any help you may be able to provide. I'm using excel 2010. thank you.

Please post the exact code.
Thanks in advance.

thank u for pointing out...here is the code....

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()

Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim FormulaSplit As Variant
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long

 'Loop through all charts in the active sheet
For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    'Loop through all series in the target chart
   For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

       'Get Source Data Range for the target series
       FormulaSplit = Split(MySeries.Formula, ",")

        'Capture the first cell in the source range then trap the color
       Set SourceRange = Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item(1)
        SourceRangeColor = SourceRange.Interior.Color

         On Error Resume Next
        'Coloring for Excel 2003
       MySeries.Interior.Color = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Border.Color = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerForegroundColorIndex = SourceRangeColor
        'Coloring for Excel 2007 and 2010
       MySeries.MarkerBackgroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerForegroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor

Next MySeries

Next oChart

End Sub
```

Comment: "*I have the code below which I was hoping ...*" and where is this code?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi-pls reply...

Comment: Fact is, I'm not a VBA programmer, not at all. But this will increase chances that somebody will help. Also mind formatting and add tags (which I did, both, now). Maybe (for the VBA programmer to come) a sample screenshot of the cells you are manipulating would be helpful, too.

Comment: @simoco - please help me with the above code...